# php - autoload not working with static method

Tags: php, autoload, spl-autoload-register

I using spl_autoload_register to autoload class like

My Structure

```
index.php
Module\Autoloader.php
Module\MyClass.php
Test\test.php
```

in `index.php` file

```
require_once ("Module\Autoloader.php");
use Module\MyClass;
include 'Test\test.php';
```

in `Module\Autoloader.php` file

```
class Autoloader {
        static public function loader($className) {
            $filename = __DIR__."/" . str_replace("\\", '/', $className) . ".php";
            echo $filename.'<br>';
            if (file_exists($filename)) {
                include($filename);
            }
        }
}
spl_autoload_register('Autoloader::loader');
```

in `Module\MyClass.php` file

```
namespace Module;
class MyClass {
    public static function run() {
        echo 'run';
    }
}
```

in `Test\test.php` file

```
MyClass::run();
```

But it has error

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'MyClass' not found in ..\Test\test.php
```

How to fix that thank

Comment: Output `$filename`, check that is it __correct__ and points to __existsing file__.

Comment: @NigelRen yes but same error

Comment: Tried `spl_autoload_register('loader');` ?

Comment: @u_mulder i just edit my code using require autoload, output is `Module/MyClass.php` but same error

Comment: try `Module\MyClass::run()` in test.php.

Comment: @Dormilich same error `Module/Module/MyClass.php` echo and `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Module\MyClass' not found ` error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your issue is that you prepend `__DIR__`

`__DIR__` is based on where the file from which it gets called resides:

> `__DIR__`
>
> The directory of the file. **If used inside an include, the directory of the included file is returned.** This is equivalent to dirname(`__FILE__`). This directory name does not have a trailing slash unless it is the root directory.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php

So because your autoloader routine resides in ./Module/

`__DIR__` will not return `/` when called from index.php but `Module`, making your finished classpath `Module/Module/MyClass.php` which obviously can't be found.

Either use another means of prepending the directory, like a predetermined list, use the first part of the namespace (so just ditch the `__DIR__`) or move the classes to location relative to directory in which your include file resides.

Comment: i don't think so. In my line `echo $filename.'<br>';` it echo correct `..\test\Module/MyClass.php` but  get fatal error `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'MyClass' not found in ..\test\Test\test.php`

Comment: You still need to `use Module\MyClass` or call it as `Module\MyClass` the requirement of proper naming doesn't change.

Comment: sorry but i don't understand, i have `use Module\MyClass;` in my `index.php` ?

Comment: that alias is used in context of that file (index.php). So in the context of the test.php file you need to either issue the use statement again or specify the fully classified name. (even if you include it)

Comment: It seem `use Module\MyClass;` in `index.php` is redundant and in `Test\test.php` must have `require_once ("Module\MyClass.php"); use Module\MyClass;` ?

Comment: it's not necessarily redundant, it's just used in the context of the code in the file index.php. You just need to make sure that the code in test.php has access to the fully qualified name as well, either through alias or by using the complete classname.

Answer (score 1):

Your  autoloader is inside the Module dir so it will  apppend an extra "Module" when you try to append  "*DIR*" to the class full name. The file location will be something like this:

../Module/Module/MyClass.php

Try to move your autoloader the same dir as index.php or change it as the following:

```
<?php

class Autoloader {
    static public function loader($className) {
        $filename = __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . '..' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 
            str_replace("\\", DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $className) . ".php";

        if (file_exists($filename)) {
            include($filename);
        } else {
            echo "$filename not found!\n";
        }
    }
}
spl_autoload_register('Autoloader::loader');
```

Comment: I try your suggest but not working.  I think `MyClass` has been loaded b/c when i echo `..\test\Module/MyClass.php` that's corrent path. but still get fatal error `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'MyClass' not found in ..\test\Test\test.php`